# Primefaces datatable select row and scope

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I use PrimeFaces 3.1 and I have to select one single row in a datatable.
I used the example in the Primefaces showcase to do it but it works only when my backing bean is in scope session, not in view, and it means that I have to do some extra jobs to remove it when the user come back on this page, what is wrong in my code?
My controller (in request scope):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Ctrlr implements Serializable{
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{myDataModel}")
    private MyDataModel dataModel;
    ...
    public void onSelectRow() {
    //do something
    }
}
```

The backingBean (I have to use session scope to have a correct working):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyDataModel extends ListDataModel<Bean> implements SelectableDataModel<Bean>, Serializable {
    ...
}
```

And my xhtml page:

```
<p:dataTable var="bean" 
        id="tableResults"
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{ctrlr.selectedBean}" 
        value="#{myDataModel}" 
        rowKey="#{bean.id}">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
            listener="#{ctrlr.onSelectRow()}"
            update=":searchForm:details:detail"/>
        ...
```

I checked in debug, and it seems that each time the controller is rebuilt (each request), the property injected is a new one, instead of re-injecting the one from the viewScope.

If someone can help me to avoid the usage of the session scope?

Comment: It doesn't need to be scopeview.

Comment: post full code as we can't see whats wrong.

Comment: I tried to put only the relevant part of my code but if you think that something is missing, tell me, I will add it.

Comment: What do you want to do with a selected row
?

Comment: I have a screen with a search form, the result of this search is displayed under the search form, and then, the user can select a row and see the detail of the selected row.

Comment: `value="#{myDataModel}" ` in your view is curious. You're binding an entire bean as the value binding of a table? Why?

Comment: myDataModel contains the list of elements I display in the datatable. Why is it surprising?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are may be following the tutorial too much.

See below an simple working example:

***Car class***

```
package test_war.test_war;

public class Car {

    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private int year;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Car(String name, Double price, int year) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}
```

***BackBean (Viewscoped)***

```
package test_war.test_war;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Car> cars;
    private Car selectedCar;

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
        cars.add(new Car("test1", 111.11, 2011));
        cars.add(new Car("test2", 711.11, 2012));
        cars.add(new Car("test3", 511.11, 2001));
        cars.add(new Car("test4", 411.11, 2000));
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    }
```

***View(main.xhtml)***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>A Simple JavaServer Faces 2.0 View</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{testBean.cars}"
            rowKey="#{car.name}" selection="#{testBean.selectedCar}"
            selectionMode="single">

            <f:facet name="header">  
            Click "View" button after selecting a row to see details  
        </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Name">  
            #{car.name}  
        </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Year">  
            #{car.year}  
        </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Price">  
            #{car.price}  
        </p:column>



            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"
                    update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" />
            </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>

        <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog"
            resizable="false" width="200" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold">

            <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">



                <h:outputText value="Name:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{testBean.selectedCar.name}" />

                <h:outputText value="Year:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{testBean.selectedCar.year}" />

                <h:outputText value="Price:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{testBean.selectedCar.price}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Output

[image: Output]

If you need the whole project as WAR/Zip file let me knw.

Comment: But the @postContruct is called only one time, according to the viewScope (a bean in this scope lives as long as you're interacting with the same JSF view in the browser window/tab. It get created upon a HTTP request and get destroyed once you postback to a different view.).

Comment: Why do I have to put everything in the constructor? Because the same code is working properly, just by putting the backing bean in session instead of view scope.

Comment: Okay if you want this as Session view then its fine.

Comment: I am using session because it does not work in view. But I want to understand why? Because session and view scopes are just a way to store some info, but the session is more like a permanent storage (across different pages) instead of view, and I want to store my data only during the time the user is on the page

Comment: I am having similar issue with multiple selection. Can anyone help?